# Facepy events data, description is missing

Tags: python, facebook

I want to use Python Facepy to fetch the events from our company Facebook site.The strange thing is that everything works fine, except the event description is missing in returned data:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI("mysecrettoken")
events = graph.get('ourcompany/events')
for x in events['data']:
    print x['description']
KeyError: 'description'
```

Except description, all data is there (name, start_time) etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event description isn't provided by the Graph api. I have to fetch it seperately for every event.